# Pass this keyword in $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass this context in $.each loop in my below code.

```
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, _foo);

function _foo (key, value) {
    console.log(this);
    alert( key + ": " + value );
}
```

How can I pass this keyword in callback function in above scenario?

Comment: which object do you want `this` to refer to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying that you want to keep the outer `this` value, then since you're iterating with jQuery, you'd need to bind the `this` value to the function.

jQuery has [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy) that'll let you do this:

```
$.each(obj, $.proxy(_foo, this));
```

---

Or use the native `.bind()` method.

```
$.each(obj. _foo.bind(this));
```

---

The native `.forEach()` lets you pass the `this` value as a second argument. But since you don't have an Array or array-like object, you can't use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.proxy() to pass a custom context to a function call

```
var obj = {
    "flammable": "inflammable",
        "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each(obj, $.proxy(_foo, this));

function _foo(key, value) {
    console.log(this);
    alert(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript bind() function, check [browser support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) (ie9 and above).

```
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each( obj, _foo.bind(obj));

function _foo (key, value) {
    console.log(this);
    //alert( key + ": " + value );
}
```